# Is there a way to use the same Docker container for all apps?

Tags: python, ubuntu, deployment, docker, dokku

I'm working on automatic deploy system. My apps use the same dependencies like `matplotlib, numpy, pandas`. The problem is that deploy takes 30+ minutes. It's too long.

I use Dokku and I want to prepare one empty container, install dependencies there using [Dockefile like this](https://github.com/humulabs/pandas-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) and then point/copy this container every time I deploy, so process would take about a minute or so (just to pull repo and prepare configs, without installing all dependencies)

Who can help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a *base* container image like you described by using a `Dockerfile` to define what need to be installed as a common basis there. Like:

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.16
...
```

Build:

```
docker build -t myBase .
```

Then all other application containers that should use that one as base container will refer to it in their own `Dockerfile` build using the [`FROM`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#from) instruction. Like:

Application `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM myBase
...
```

Comment: well but how can I create a base-container?

Comment: I need your help again. how shall I use Dokku with new Dockerfile? My flask apps are not deploying now